# How do I copy variables in a text by using a copy button?

Tags: javascript, html, text, copy

I'm fairly new to coding, so excuse me if my description is a bit vague.

I created a "Copy" button in JavaScript:

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("text copied, copy in the text-area")
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="myInput">
  <p>
    Rope color: <strong><span id="colorName"></span></strong><br>
    Type of clamp <strong><span id="clampName"></span></strong><br>
    Rope length: 130cm <strong><span id="ropeLength"></span></strong>
  </p>
</span>
<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('myInput')">Copy</button>
```

Now the button works fine, but this function only copies the text from the `div`, not the variables.
The variables being:

- `colorName` (such as red, blue etc)
- `clampName` (such as strong, expert etc.)
- `ropeLength` (always starts with "+" and then "XXXcm")

How can I make sure everything (text & variables) is being copied?

EDIT: It seems the problem is different... When the only click is directly on the button, the copy works. When you click anywhere but the button, and then on the button. The button does not function/copy anymore. I think this is the problem since the Variables are filled by clicking a form (selecting red as a color for example). Any help with that?

Comment: For clrayfication: You mean copy html objects instead of variables?

Comment: Actually, the markup is copied to the clipboard, but you can't see it if you paste the text to a textarea, or ex. to a text editor. If you'd paste it to a HTMLElement with contenteditable  attribute set (or to an app showing HTML by default), you can see the markup has been copied (try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cwshto6k/)).

Answer (score 0):

This below fiddle based on your solution seems to be working fine. The only change I did was to move the click event to a event listener.

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", CopyToClipboard);
function CopyToClipboard() {
    var containerid = "myInput";
    ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6kz4weu/

Comment: Hey, I checked your code in the link, and when I first click on the button (without clicking anywhere else) it works. But if i first click next to the button (anywhere but the button), and then click on the button... it does not work. Do you know what's causing that?

Comment: Maybe this specific problem is not in your additions, but in my original code... and maybe why it wasn't working in the first place.